# creating python files from pycharm terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

How does one create a python file from pycharm terminal.In VS Code they use "code {name}" so I want something similar to that but in pycharm.

I am getting an error "zsh:command not found:code"

Answer (score 3):

you can create a python file from the pycharm terminal just by typing

```
touch myPythonFile.py
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting->Keymap
2. Search "new"
3. Under "Pyhon Community Edition" there will be an option for "Python File"
4. Add a new shortcut to this option (SHIFT+N is usually unassigned)